# What is the best way to accumulate items' IDs before sending them to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ListView its item is selectable. I want after select some items (Client side using JQuery) to send their IDs the selected elements to the server for saving them.

What is the best way to accumulate them in the client side?

Is it using a Hidden field with a seperator between IDs ?

Or is there a better approuch?

**Edit:**

Notes: ID's are integers, The server side technology is ASP.Net.

Comment: Why don't you use a JavaScript variable for this? I don't see why you would need to alter the HTML.

Comment: How to access to it from the server side and getting the values?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru javascript variables don't post in form submission, you can only send through AJAX. Saving in hidden is best.

Comment: @Adeel Neither do inputs. He says he's using jQuery so doing an AJAX request should be the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

Are the IDs just integers? If they're guaranteed to never contain the separator, then that would be a pretty easy approach. Another approach is to have lots of hidden inputs, but I think just one would be simpler. How are you passing the data back? Through a form submit, or AJAX? That might affect your decision too.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax and **send the id's concatenated with a string** and then process at the server side **.**
Using **javascript** or **jquery** using a **loop** concatenate the ids like say
`1,2,3,4` and pass it as a variable to server

at server just split then and serve as your use.
hope this helps

Comment: "process at the server side Using javascript or jquery" I think you're not getting the whole client-server picture. JavaScript is only on the client. Or did you miss a dot there?

Comment: sorry i forget to put a full stop ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving those IDs as the 'values' of the List Items. Each Item has 'Text' and 'Value' attribute. Text is what it displays to user and 'Value' is supposedly the ID.

Also you can add custom attributes using data- prefix.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is acumulate them in an array, but you can't pass an array to the server, so at the time of passing that array, just transform the array in a serializable string (you can pass it by get or post, whatever you want, and deserialize the string at destination.

I don't which language are you using at server side, but normally you have several tools to deserialize in jsp, php, as well as in asp, for example.